# Remove Whitespace Inside Array

Tags: php

I have an array where some of its elements are filled with lots of whitespace and `\n`. I would like to remove this whitespace and `\n`.

I have been using the following code, but the compiler says that my code does not work for arrays.

```
//My code that removes white-space    
$input = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $myArray);

//Sample of array with white space
$myArray = array(
    'extra spaces' => '<div>     </div>',
    'return' => '<b>\n</b>',
)

//What I want the array to look like
$myArray = array(
    'extra spaces' => '<div></div>',
    'return' => '<b></b>',
)
```

Comment: You might be interested in PHP's [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php): "Applies [a] user-defined callback function to each element of [an] array." A simple `foreach` loop will probably get you there, too.

Comment: @showdev not trying to steal your answer, I just submitted it when I saw your comment :\

Comment: @JochemKuijpers No worries. Thanks for posting your answer.

Comment: If I understand correctly your question, this should work: $cleanArray = preg_replace( '/[ \n]/', '', $myArray);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a foreach loop to get through all the elements in your array:

```
foreach($myArray as $key => $val)
{
    $myArray[$key]=preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $value);
}
```

I haven't actually checked the code, and haven't ever been good with regex, but assuming your replace works fine, it should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// loop through each element and apply the function
foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {
    $myArray[$key] = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $value);
}
```

Or make a function that does this and use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

Note that I'm replacing your whitespace by an **empty string**, not by a single space (like you and other answers did). This way you will completely remove the whitespace, instead of replacing it with a space.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you call `preg_replace`, `$myArray` is not yet defined. Switch the definition of `$myArray` and the call to `preg_replace`:

   ```
   //Sample of array with white space#

   $myArray = array(
       'extra spaces' => '<div>     </div>',
       'return' => '<b>\n</b>',
   )

   //My code that removes white-space    
   $input = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $myArray);
   ```
2. If you want `'<div>     </div>'` to become `'<div></div>'`, you shouldn't replace `'/\s+/'` with `' '`, but with `''`.
3. `\n` is considered a line break (and thus matches `'/\s+/'`) only within double quotes, not within single quotes. Change `'<b>\n</b>'` to `"<b>\n</b>"` or fix your regular expression.

Comment: My guess is that this was a simple sketch of what he was trying to accomplish, hence  the `Sample of array with white space` and `What I want the array to look like`

Comment: Sweet, I didn't know [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) works on arrays : "If subject is an array, then the search and replace is performed on every entry of subject, and the return value is an array as well." @icu222much What was the exact error message regarding "code does not work for arrays"?

Comment: @JochemKuijpers No need to be sorry. It has become quite hard to tell whether the error is in the original source code or within the question. A lot of people don't bother to check whether the source code they post really exhibits the problem that they are facing. I came to the conclusion not to bother either, do my best to help and let the OP decide which part of my answer is useful.